# code runs progressively increasing number of times for a event

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, socket.io

I don't know how to explain this properly so please bear with me.
this is my server code nothing wrong with this well i dont think there is

```
const latest_time_ref = ref(config.db,"latest_msg/time")
const latest_msg_ref = ref(config.db, "latest_msg")

io.on("connect", (socket) => {
  socket.on("user_added", (uname) => {
    username = uname;
    console.log("a user connected");
  });

  socket.on("msg_sent", (uname, msg, time) => {
    set(ref(config.db, "users/" + username + "/messages/" + time), {
      message: msg,
    });
    set(latest_msg_ref, { message: msg, uname: uname,time:{time:time} });
  });
  onChildChanged(latest_time_ref, () => {
    onValue(latest_msg_ref, (snapshot) => {
      socket.emit("ting",snapshot.val().message,snapshot.val().uname,snapshot.val().time.time)
    });
  });

});

server.listen(3000, console.log("server listning on port 3000"));
```

and this is client side

```
var form = document.getElementById('form')
var msg_cont = document.getElementById('input')

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (msg_cont.value) {
        socket.emit('msg_sent', uname, msg_cont.value, new Date().getTime())
        console.log(new Date().getTime())
        msg_cont.value=""
    }
})
// var i=0
socket.on('ting', (msg,username,time) => {
    console.log("meow")

})
```

everything works fine I can get data from form and put it in database get data from database but whenever "ting" event is triggered in client side "meow" gets printed progressively more times like every time i send a message there is same message repeated one more time then before
would greatly appreciate if some one made me understand whaat is happening and why is it happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a listener with `on...` to Firebase Realtime Database, that is a persistent listener that:

1. Retrieves the current value of the node immediately, or at least as soon as possibl.
2. Then continues to listen to changes in the value of the node.

Since you call `onValue` each time `onChildChanged` happens, you likely end up with more and more of these persistent `onValue` listeners over time.

If you only want to [get the value from the Realtime Database once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) whenever `onChildChanged` happens, use `get` instead of `onValue`:

```
onChildChanged(latest_time_ref, () => {
  get(latest_msg_ref).then((snapshot) => {
    socket.emit("ting",snapshot.val().message,snapshot.val().uname,snapshot.val().time.time)
  });
});
```